# Level 6 - Getting past the drone

Tags: untrusted

In level 6 of Untrusted, how do I avoid the attack drone? I've tried creating a new object type that could act as a blocker, but the drone manages to get around it, and I'm convinced there has to be an easier solution that I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drone has a very simple "AI" that chooses moves in a dumb way, so you can exploit that to trap it.

> It checks to see which direction is the closest and commits to that prior to determining whether or not a move in that direction is valid.  Thus, you can make it so that moves that get it close to you by those standards are consistently invalid, and it won't catch up to you in time.

The way I exploited this was:

> I created a little "cage" out of blocks that I knew the drone would prefer to move into.  That way, I could move past it and it wouldn't catch me.

The full solution I used was:

> ```
> map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-3, 10, 'block');
> map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-4, 10, 'block');
> map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-5, 11, 'block');
> map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-4, 12, 'block');
> ```

Comment: It also doe not have validation for only 1 player, so `map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-5, 11, 'player');` gives it a different target to attack.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually rebind the `moveToward` variable, and the re-bound function will be used by the drone. This allows you to trivially reprogram the drone to do movement you want.

Answer (score 3):

or you can build self defences drones :)

```
map.defineObject('selfDefenceDrone', {
'type': 'dynamic',
'symbol': 'X',
'color': 'green',
'onCollision': function (player) {
player.killedBy('an attack drone');
console.log('killled!');
},
'behavior': function (me) {
moveToward(me, 'attackDrone');
console.log(me.findNearest('attackDrone'));
console.log('-------------');
}
});

map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-9, 12, 'selfDefenceDrone');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-5, 16, 'selfDefenceDrone');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-5, 8, 'selfDefenceDrone');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-1, 14, 'selfDefenceDrone');
```